# NSURLSession didCompleteWithError:gets called with NSError is nil

Tags: ios, nsurlsession, aws-sdk, nserror, nsurlsessiontask

Scenario is taking the app to background and foreground multiple times  when its uploading is in progress,didCompleteWithError: method is called while taking app to foreground with error parameter is null. Probabilty is 1/3.

How do i find out what went wrong as error parameter does not give anything.

Comment: I guess this can give you any hint:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19236440/when-does-nsurlsession-run

Comment: it didn't help.Is there any other way to get what causes nil error simultaneously not completing with success

Comment: HI Vani, did you resolved this issue?

Comment: not able to resolve and update here if you could find any solution.

Comment: @Vani. Try to check - URLSession:didBecomeInvalidWithError: by implementing NURLSession delegate:https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionDelegate_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSURLSessionDelegate/URLSession:didBecomeInvalidWithError:

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that didCompleteWithError report **only** client side error, otherwise is nil. iOS doc said:

*"Server errors are not reported through the error parameter. 
**The only errors your delegate receives through the error parameter are client-side errors**, 
such as being unable to resolve the hostname or connect to the host.*"

This is the [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/NSURLSessionConcepts/NSURLSessionConcepts.html) to the documentation.

If you want to check session's errors you have to implement session protocol delegate

```
- URLSession:didBecomeInvalidWithError:
```

Remember to invalidate the session after stop using it.
So if you create an NSURLSession like this:

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *backgroundConfigurationObject = [NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier:@"applycasession"];
    self.backgroundSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:backgroundConfigurationObject delegate:self delegateQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];
```

When you finish to use it you have to call:

```
 [self.backgroundSession invalidateAndCancel];
```

Please read the documents about "***Life Cycle of URL Session***" at this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/NSURLSessionConcepts/NSURLSessionConcepts.html)