# URLSession didCompleteWithError nil error

Tags: ios, objective-c, networking, ios9

Working on an IOS9 app that is doing a background URLSession in a controller that is a NSURLSessionDelegate. Here is how I start it:

```
    self.session_data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:src];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    NSURLSessionConfiguration *backgroundConfigObject = [NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier: @"myBackgroundSessionIdentifier"];
    self.session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration: backgroundConfigObject delegate: self delegateQueue: [NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];

    self.download = [self.session dataTaskWithRequest: request ];
    [self.download resume];
```

So far so good. I implement the three delegate methods. 'didReceiveData' is called first and I store the data.

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session
      dataTask:(NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTask
     didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{

   NSLog(@"%s",__func__);
   [self.session_data appendData:data];
}
```

Right after that 'didCompleteWithError' is called. The 'completionHandler' handler is never called.

What is confusing about 'didCompleteWithError' message is that the actual error object is nil. I have seen some similar unanswered questions. I am not leaving the controller/view while loading. Do I need to move that functionality into AppDelegate?

Comment: Have you set NSTransport security in .plist ?

Answer (score 7):

Apple doc said that *didCompleteWithError* report **only** client side error, otherwise is nil:

"Server errors are not reported through the error parameter. **The only errors your delegate receives through the error parameter are client-side errors,** such as being unable to resolve the hostname or connect to the host."

This is the [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionTaskDelegate_protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSURLSessionTaskDelegate/URLSession:task:didCompleteWithError:) to the documentation.

If you want to check other errors like session's errors you have to implement session protocol delegate

```
- URLSession:didBecomeInvalidWithError:
```

For more details, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31262564/nsurlsession-didcompletewitherrorgets-called-with-nserror-is-nil#comment62009932_31262564) answer