# didcompletewitherror return nil even for request with bad url

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlsession, nsurl, nsurlsessionconfiguration

I have a `Nsurlsesiondownloadtask` running which I use to download an XML file  locally hosted at say : url - http://10.232.254.59/catalogue.xml

Problem is when I use  url - http://10.232.254.59/catalogue.x or 
url - http://10.232.254.59/catal  or any other combination without changing the IP, `didcompletewitherror` delegate gives me error= (null).

```
//  MainViewController.m
@interface MainViewController ()
{   
    NSURLSessionDownloadTask *download;  
} 
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSURLSession *backgroundSession;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  NSURLSessionConfiguration *ConfigurationObject = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    ConfigurationObject.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 10.0;
    ConfigurationObject.timeoutIntervalForResource = 10.0;
    self.backgroundSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:ConfigurationObject delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];

    [self LoadMediaUrl_StartTask_StartActivityIndicator];
}
-(void)LoadMediaUrl_StartTask_StartActivityIndicator{
    NSURL *url ;
    url = [self mediaUrlFromSettings];
    if(url.absoluteString.length != 0){
        download = [self.backgroundSession downloadTaskWithURL:url];
        [download resume];
        --do more stuff---
    }     
}
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(nonnull NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didFinishDownloadingToURL:(nonnull NSURL *)location{

NSLog(@"didFinishDownloadingToURL called");

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
*** start the parser ***
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Success" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" Catalogue Download Success! Press OK to Load New Media List."] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:@"cancel", nil];
    alert.tag = ALERT_VIEW_DOWNLOAD_SUCCESS;
    [alert show];
});


  -(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(nonnull NSURLSessionTask *)task didCompleteWithError:(nullable NSError *)error
{  

       NSLog(@"didCompleteWithError error :  %@",[error localizedDescription]);
    if(error != nil){

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self.downloadActivityIndicator stopAnimating];
            [self.downloadProgressView setHidden:YES];
            self.DownloadImageView.alpha = 1.0;
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" Catalogue Download Failed ! %s%@","\n",[error localizedDescription]] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:@"Retry", nil];
            alert.tag =ALERT_VIEW_DOWNLOAD_FAILED;
            [alert show];
        });
    }

    download = nil;
}
```

I get proper error in `didCompleteWithError` when IP is changed but not when I change IP/* , because of which even in case of bad url , download success alert  shows up.
I also receive the `didFinishDownloadingToURL` delegate call even in bad url case .
I am calling `LoadMediaUrl_StartTask_StartActivityIndicator` at few more places and using the same backgroundSession obj.

Could anyone please  tell me what might be the cause ?

Answer (score 0):

I think i got the cause 
[URLSession didCompleteWithError nil error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36505444/urlsession-didcompletewitherror-nil-error)

Its because it reports only client side errors , but not sure how this scenarious qualifies for server problem.

Comment: Don't post followup questions in an answer. A posted answer should fully answer the question, not ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

To detect server errors (e.g. 404), implement the didReceiveResponse delegate method.  From there, check the httpStatusCode property in the NSHTTPURLResponse object.  You'll have to cast the NSURLResponse to an NSHTTPURLResponse pointer first.